# how to catch an error when using mongoose to query something

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am studying mongoose, and I have a example of a query:

```
async findOne(condition, constraints) {
        try {
            let data = await User.findOne(condition, constraints ? constraints : null);
            console.log(`findOne success--> ${data}`);
            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`findOne error--> ${error}`);
            return error;
        }
    }
```

In my opinion，this code will catch errors when the method findOne won't work. Then I saw in the console there is a 'findOne success--> null' when the method findOne returns null. How can I make the try/catch work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mongoose's `findOne()` return `null` when there is no document found and `null` is not an error.

You can use [`.orFail()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-orFail) which throw an error if no documents match the given filter. This is handy for integrating with async/await, because `orFail()` saves you an extra if statement to check if no document was found:

```
let data = await User.findOne(condition, constraints ? constraints : null).orFail();
```

Or just throw an error when there is no result

```
try {
    let data = await User.findOne(condition, constraints ? constraints : null);
    if(!data) {
      throw new Error('no document found');
    }
    console.log(`findOne success--> ${data}`);
    return data;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(`findOne error--> ${error}`);
    return error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add more conditions in the if of try block and throw a customError which will be catching at the catch block.

i hope this will solve the issue.

please see the below snippet

```
async findOne(condition, constraints) {
  try {
      let data = await User.findOne(condition, constraints ? constraints : null);
      console.log(`findOne success--> ${data}`);
      if(data){
        // do your logic
        return data;
      }
      const customError = {
        code : 500,
        message: 'something went wrong'
      }
      throw customError
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(`findOne error--> ${error}`);
      return error;
  }
}
```